# How to interpolate a value from an object inside interation in Emblem.js?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, emblem.js

I have the following code in an Emblem.js template:

```
each segment in controller
  .panel.panel-default
    .panel-heading
      h4.panel-title
        a data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{{segment.id}}"
          span {{segment.title}}
    div id="collapse{{segment.id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse in"
```

What I'm actually trying to achieve is to interpolate object data into the HTML attributes. I been trying to `{{segment.id}}` but that render some script tags along with the value which is not what I'm looking for. Is there another way to do this?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until [HTMLBars](https://github.com/tildeio/htmlbars) comes out, Ember.js is going to need to insert placeholder tags to manipulate the DOM. You have two options:

1. Create a computed property that will join the strings for you, then use `bind-attr` to apply the property to the ID or class.
2. Use the [unbound helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_unbound). This will do what you want, but it won't update the property if it changes.

I suggest doing the first if you can.

Answer (score 1):

if the data isn't going to change, you can use `unbound` and it'll just jam it in there without script tags.

```
each segment in controller
  .panel.panel-default
    .panel-heading
      h4.panel-title
        a data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{{unbound segment.id}}"
          span {{segment.title}}
    div id="collapse{{segment.id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse in"
```